# Помогите пожалуйста сделать такой эффект scroll как в примере

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal, прокрутка

Вот [пример](http://www.phosphenefx.com/credits).

Пока накидал скелет:

```css
.box{
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.imgbox{
  background:red;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  height: 30vh;
}
.wrap{
  width: 20%;
   float: left;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 100vh;
   -ms-overflow-style: none;  // IE 10+
      overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;  // Firefox
      &::-webkit-scrollbar { 
       display: none;  // Safari and Chrome
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
   </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
   </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
   </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
    <div class="imgbox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

как сделать с помощью translate3d. Спасибо.

Comment: А если стащить всё с донора? css и js?

Comment: вопросы должены быть самодостаточны, всё описание должно быть в тексте вашего вопроса, чтобы можно было понять суть без ссылок на внешние ресурсы

Comment: без ссылок не понятно как должно работать, а на вопрос с донора тоскать, для среднего уровня тяжело, все сделано на объектах